# Can i search all push ids from the database without having to do it on the app side

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about searching the database. Right now the database looks like this. first child = "hello" then second child is a pushid. and every push id has a few ids i want to look up. Can I somehow search through all push ids and return only the ones with the correct id or do i have to get all push ids and manually go through them on the app side?

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("hello").child(***this is the push id***).child("id to look up");
```

To recap: can I search all push ids on the database side and return only the children with the last id somehow?

If this doesn't make sense please tell me to clarify something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the child node under a list, you can do:

```
var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("hello");
var query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
```

And then you use that query to read the values, or bind to a widget.

---

To get nodes where a specific child property matches a specific value, you'd use this query:

```
var query = ref.orderByChild("id").equalTo("abc");
```

Comment: No i want the full node, where the child node is the id im looking for.

Comment: A mysql query would looke something like... SELECT * FROM hello WHERE id = "abc";

Comment: I added an example of that to. Going forward it'd really help if you edit your question to: 1) show the JSON you are querying (as text, no screenshots or descriptions). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) What nodes you expect to get back, and why.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for other questions, that was exactly what i was looking for. The push id is confusing me a lot.